# add new line to output file python

Tags: python, io

hi i want to write the newline character to an output file so here is my code:

```
a=['\n:001000', '\r:10111', ' :000', '!:01101111101', '":0010011', "':0010010110", '(:00100101111110110', '):00100101111110111', ',:101100', '-:1011011011', '.:0100100', '0:011011111001101', '1:0110111110010', '2:1011011000111', '3:011011111001110']

text_file = open("Output.txt", "wb")
    for t in a:
        text_file.write(t+" ")
```

but my output is not what i expected:

```
:001000  :10111   :000  !:01101111101  ":0010011  ':0010010110  (:00100101111110110  ):00100101111110111  ,:101100  -:1011011011  .:0100100  0:011011111001101  1:0110111110010  2:1011011000111  3:011011111001110
```

does anyone know how to actually write the newline character to the output ???

i want something like eg: \n:001000 \r:10111 etc

Comment: Writing the newline character is as simple as appending "\n" or '\n' to the print statement as @Michel pointed out. Furthermore, the '\r' carriage return works, look at the file in a text editor! Could you please try and more accurately phrase your intentions? What was unexpected about the output you got? Is it the same in the file? What should it have looked like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing those characters, just look at the `repr`

```
>>> a=['\n:001000 ', '\r:10111 ', ' :000 ', '!:01101111101 ', '":0010011 ', "':0010010110 ", '(:00100101111110110 ', '):00100101111110111 ', ',:101100 ', '-:1011011011 ', '.:0100100 ', '0:011011111001101 ', '1:0110111110010 ', '2:1011011000111 ', '3:011011111001110 ']
>>> with open("Output.txt", "wb") as f:
        for t in a:
            f.write(t + " ")


>>> with open("Output.txt", "rb") as f:
        print repr(f.read()) # representation


'\n:001000  \r:10111   :000  !:01101111101  ":0010011  \':0010010110  (:00100101111110110  ):00100101111110111  ,:101100  -:1011011011  .:0100100  0:011011111001101  1:0110111110010  2:1011011000111  3:011011111001110  '
```

Or maybe you are asking to escape those characters to print them raw:

```
>>> with open("Output.txt", "wb") as f:
        for t in a:
            f.write((t + " ").encode('string_escape'))


>>> with open("Output.txt", "rb") as f:
        print f.read()


\n:001000  \r:10111   :000  !:01101111101  ":0010011  \':0010010110  (:00100101111110110  ):00100101111110111  ,:101100  -:1011011011  .:0100100  0:011011111001101  1:0110111110010  2:1011011000111  3:011011111001110
```

Comment: i just wish to read the first line as there are other things after that first line that i dont put it on the question cause i just stuck at that question

Comment: @TommyNgo To read the first line change `.read` to `.readline`

Answer (score 0):

The new line character is '\n'

Comment: yes i wanna write it out to the output file but that is the result that i get.

Comment: But you write " "  instead of "\n"

Comment: the space is just the space to separate \n:001000 from \n:001000